# How can I create a dynamic model controller inside a directive in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, model, controller, angularjs-directive

When we desire to create a model controller we do:

```
 <group ng-model="data"></group>
```

On the directive:

```
 control.directive('group', [function($compile){
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
     require: 'ngModel',
     priority: 0,
     link:  function link(scope, elem, attrs, control) {

        // Manipulate model controller here!
        console.log(control);

     }

   }
}]);
```

But what have I should do to insert (create) a new model controller to my directive dynamically? My requirement is to create a model only if ngModel attribute was not provided. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you just want to: a) make ngModel optional or b) do you want to add an ngModel if one is missing -> if b) then where are you planning to get the info to populate the dynamically created ngModel?

Comment: I need add one if it is missing!

Comment: Okay, so say I have this: `<div></div>` and you want to dynamically make it `<div ng-model='scopeProp'></div>` - how do you know what value to add as scopeProp - will it be always the same value?

Comment: Yes! I will not use the model at all. I just need the controller to set form validity (I am creating a group of fields. Group directive will be used just to perform group validations). In this case, ngModel could be anything! I would want access this way: form.<groupNameDirective>.$invalid

Comment: Do you not have control over the template?

Comment: No! I don't have it! I would want to create one that contains $setValidity function as we have when use ngModel